# map function to operate on two collections in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I need a map function to operate on two collections (sequences), something like this:

```
map((col1Item, col2Item) => { col1Item.text.contains(col2Item); }, col1, col2)
```

I know C# has `Enumerable.Select`, but it accepts one collection. Are there "more than one collection" alternative?

**UPDATE**:

My current solution is something like the following:

`if (elements.Select ((element, index) => { element.Text.Contains (expectedTexts[index]); }).All ( res => res == true)) {
    // do something if texts of each element from elements seq contains correspondent text from expectedTexts seq
}`

Though I am still curious about more classic "functional style" alternative.

Comment: It is not clear what do you want. Can you provide an example collection and desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [IEnumerable.Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx). This takes two IEnumerable instances, applies a function to the elements at the same index of each, producing an collection of the results. For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> a;
IEnumerable<string> b;

// result will contain the concatenated strings
IEnumerable<string> result = a.Zip(b, (fromA, fromB) => fromA + fromB);
```

Comment: I guess you wanted to write `a.Zip(b, ...`. But seems like that is the answer... Will try.. Thank you a lot!